# How to make webpack-dev-server to serve the same from any subdomain?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

My SPA application makes AJAX requests based on subdomain. It basically extracts the current subdomain from `window.location.hostname` and set it as global var.

Currently what I get when I try to access through subdomains is this:

[image]

What I need? I need to webpack dev server to treat any subdomain.localhost:8080 in order to make it load the content normally as if there was not a subdomain. Basically to ignore subdomains and serve the same since, in my case, that ought to be treated by the front-end application itself.

What I have tried already: I tried to setup `proxy`, `proxyTables` and `allowedHosts` but I didn't success.

By the way, When I serve the built files in my express.js server it behaves exactly as I need though: serving the same static content regardless of which is the subdomain.

System specs: Chrome and MacOS Sierra.

Also, I'm using vue-cli webpack template the latest.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
disableHostCheck: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your webpack is by default binded on a hostname and will only answer by that name.

To remove that limitation use the command-line parameter `host` as follows: `--host 0.0.0.0`.

Also edit your **hosts file** to add all used subdomains pointing to `127.0.0.1`:

```
127.0.0.1 sub.localhost
127.0.0.1 other.localhost
```

Usually your hosts file is located at:

- `/etc/hosts` for posix systems like unix, mac and linux;
- `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` for win32 systems;